# Get nested data from JSON

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a JSON file. It looks like this:

```
{
  "products": [
    {
      "category": "Napoje",
      "products": {
        "product1": "Piwo",
        "product2": "Wino",
        "product3": "Cola",
        "product4": "Sprite"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to use the data in a React component. Is this the right way to use it?

```
componentDidMount(){
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/products')
            .then(r => r.json())
            .then( data => {
                this.setState({})
                let products = Object.keys(data).map(id => data[id]);
                this.setState({
                    products: products
                })
            });
    }
```

I want to keep it in state.

Comment: We will need to see how you are using the `state` in your component. But generally, the idea is there.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use the returned object from `'r.json()'` and save it to state?

what you have done was loop through the returned object and create a new object which seems unnecessary unless you need to modify the original object.

Below code would be enough I guess.

```
componentDidMount(){
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/products')
            .then(r => r.json())
            .then( data => {
                this.setState({
                    products: data 
                })
            });
    }
```